# express.js unexpected token . error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I got unexpected token . at line `Ad.getAdCredit` and I wonder why. I already included Ad like `const Ad = require('model/ad')`, can't spot anything wrong with below code.

```
router.put('/task/status', (req, res) => {

    const { id } = req.body
    const { status, user_id, ad_id } = req.body

    if(status === 'approve'){

        async.series([
            Ad.getAdCredit(ad_id, callback) => {
                callback(err, resp)
            },
            (err, callback) => {

                async.parallel([
                    Task.updateStatus(id, status, (err, resp, callback) => {
                        callback(err, resp)
                    }),
                    Credit.addCredit(user_id, amount, callback) => {
                        callback(err, resp)
                    }
                ], (err, callback) => {
                    if(err){
                        return handleError(err, 'Failed to update task status', res)
                    }

                    res.json({
                        success: true,
                        result: {task: resp}
                    })
                })
            }
        ])

    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Ad.getAdCredit(ad_id, callback) => {
>     callback(err, resp) 
> },
> ```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, but you can either:

**Call an existing function**

```
 Ad.getAdCredit(ad_id, callback)
```

**Create a function with arrow syntax**

```
Ad.getAdCredit = (ad_id, callback) => {
     callback(err, resp) 
 }
```

---

You are mashing up the syntax for both, which doesn't make sense and is not allowed.